# Connecting 15/21V to GPIO to read an on/off state

Tags: gpio, electronics, voltage

I am working with GPIO where I want to read a vacuum sensor's output voltage.
Using a voltmeter from the output to the pi's ground, I measured the voltages.

- ON State: 21V
- OFF State: 15V
  I know that GPIO is designed to only receive 3.3v for input. How can I wire the pi so that it can receive the vacuum sensor's output without damaging the pi?

Here is a related link that I looked at:
[Connecting 15V to GPIO w/o dividing voltage](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57641/connecting-15v-to-gpio-w-o-dividing-voltage)

If there are any components that I have to purchase to make this work, please let me know.

Thank You!

Comment: Might be easiest to use a voltage divider to reduce the voltage and a ADC chip to read the analogue voltage.

Comment: what is preventing you from supplying the vacuum sensor with lower voltage?

Comment: jsotola, The vacuum switch is rated 10.8 to 30 VCC. We are currently supplying it 24V. We could supply it less voltage, but it would still be over 3.3V.

Comment: This is not a Pi question but about designing a circuit to connect to an unspecified source. If the device ACTUALLY returns those voltages it would difficult to detect the 7:5 change in value without some external electronics. I expect the voltages you measure are an artefact of the circuit and would vary with loading.

Answer (score 0):

The pi is very sensitive when it comes to the tension on the GPIO. When you are working with higher tensions, be very careful.

I would use an opto-coupler to protect my Pi.

[image]

Your zener would be somewhere above 15V. The resistor on the led-side of the opto-coupler depends on the zener value and the opto-coupler that is used..